# Auto-update do publish no Visual Studio zerando o banco de dados

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013

A pouco tempo precisei criar um instalador para aplicação desktop em c#, e como no visual studio 2013 existia o Publish que já criava o Setup e Auto-Update acabei utilizando ele pela comodidade, mas agora estou com um problema, todas as vezes que publico uma nova versão da aplicação e ela é baixada, ele cria um novo banco de dados vazio e de alguma forma "seta" esse banco de dados para a aplicação. Se eu mandar restaurar a aplicação para a versão anterior, o banco de dados antigo esta lá intacto com todos os dados.

Imagino que seja fácil resolver esse problema, e deve ser apenas algum parâmetro que não me atentei na hora de configurar, o problema que não sei bem ao certo pelo o que procurar. E as pesquisas pelo google me devolvem resultado que não são realmente a resposta para o meu problema.

Comment: Sua aplicação usa Entity Framework?

Comment: Não. Tudo na mão mesmo.

Comment: Como é o seu procedimento de publicação? Consegue descrever as etapas?

Comment: Ta bem default mesmo, Build -> publish -> next next next finish.

Comment: Nas Configurações que mexi foi só o básico de configurar para procurar atualizações, e onde deveria procurar, mas não vi nada referente a banco de dados

Comment: Sim, mas e as *connection strings* do `App.Config` pra onde elas apontam? Como elas ficam ao final da publicação?

Comment: a string de conexão do banco de dados esta assim: `Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela sua *connection string*, você usa LocalDB:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\Database1.mdf;I‌​ntegrated Security=True
```

Há duas possibilidades:

- Ou o arquivo `Database1.mdf` é sobrescrito na instalação;
- Ou a publicação cria um novo arquivo `.mdf`.

No primeiro caso, verifique o arquivo `Database1.mdf` usando o [SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=42299). O *server name* é `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB`.

Já para o segundo, é o `App.config` que possivelmente está apontando para outro arquivo. Aí acho interessante você instalar [uma extensão que transforme o `App.config` controladamente](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859) e configurar a *connection string* manualmente.

Comment: O problema era o arquivo mdf mesmo. O atributo `Copy to Output Directory` estava `Copy always`. Vlw